# Curl - headerfunction and write function called when an error occures (access denied)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, curl, libcurl

I am using curl to perform downloads, the operation works as expected for the most part. When I start a download headers are sent to my header function,data to the writefile.

The problem is in the event of an error the error message access denied for example, the error message text is sent to both the header function and the writeFile. So what ends up happening when I execute a retry I find a file about 1k in size (the error message) and I start writing to the end of it.

Is this the expected behavior? (error text sent to both functions)

```
curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, postCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,writeFile);
curl_easy_setopt(session, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &downloadContent);
lastCURLCode = curl_easy_perform(session);
curl_easy_getinfo (session, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &lastHttpResponse);
```

Comment: Are you saying that the same content from the server's "access denied" page is being sent to both functions?  Or does the header function receive just the headers of the error page, and the write function receive just the content of the error page?  I would expect the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header and body callbacks get header and content no matter which HTTP response that is received unless you set [CURLOPT_FAILONERROR](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTFAILONERROR).

Comment: thanks, now that I think about it makes sense that the body of the error message you be part of the data callback